# Prevent Mapstruct from overriding a method

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

Is there a way to prevent `mapstruct` from overriding a specific method that I have provided an implementation for in my mapper class?

I have a method `entityDTOToVehicle` that I have provided an implementation for in my mapper class `EntityMapper`, when generating mappings for this class, `mapstruct` ignores the provided implementation and overrides my implementation with its own.

- I have tried making the method `final`, it doesn't work
- I have tried using `qualifiedByName` in `@Mapping`, it doesn't work

My mapper class looks like this:

```
public abstract class EntityMapper {

    public static final EntityMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(EntityMapper.class);
    
    protected final Vehicle EntityDTOToVehicle(EntityDTO EntityDTO) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

        //My Implementation Here

        return vehicle;
    }

    @Mapping(target = "vehicle.property1",  source = "vehicleProperty1")
    @Mapping(target = "vehicle.property2",  source = "vehicleProperty2")
    public abstract Entity map(EntityDTO dto);
}
```

Mapstruct then generates an implementation like this:

```
@Component
public class EntityMapperImpl extends EntityMapper {

    @Override
    public Entity map(EntityDTO dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Entity entity = new Entity();
        .
        .
        .
        entity.setTransport( entityDTOToVehicle( dto ) );

        return entity;
    }

     /** 
     * This is the method I'd like to prevent mapstruct from overriding  */
    protected Vehicle entityDTOToVehicle(EntityDTO entityDTO) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

        //Mapstruct's Implementation

        return vehicle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@Named` on your implementation.

```
@Named(value = "mappingName")
protected Vehicle EntityDTOToVehicle(EntityDTO EntityDTO) {
    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

    //My Implementation Here

    return vehicle;
}
```

Then attach it to the abstract mapper:

```
@Mappings(value ={
    @Mapping(target = "vehicle.property1",  source = "vehicleProperty1")
    @Mapping(target = "vehicle.property2",  source = "vehicleProperty2")
    @Mapping(source = "fieldWithVehiclePropChangeItToYours", target = "transport", qualifiedByName = "mappingName"),
}
public abstract Entity map(EntityDTO dto);
```